# Custom SQLite Loader - listen to update from another Fragment/Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

In my app I have an SQLIte DB.
I have a ListView that requires data from the DB, so I thought I'd give Loaders a try.

I have 2 fragments:

Fragment A - has a ListView with an adapter that gets its data from the DB using a custom Loader.

Fragment B - this is an "edit item" fragment, where items are edited and then updated in the DB.

Since Fragment B can't (and shouldn't from what I understand) access the Loader in Fragment A, editing items in Fragment B does not update Fragment A.

How should I address this issue? Can this at all be solved using Loaders?

Comment: all you need is a well written custom ContentProvider,  see Notepad  tutorial

Comment: You mean using ContentObserver? I thought of implementing a ContentObserver, but it is s big overkill for what I need.

Comment: no,  ContentProvider,  see how to use a ContentResolver for registering the Uri and notifing the changes, refer to Notepad provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both fragments are in the same Activity, they can get access to the same `loader`. I think your problem is that you are initializing the loader inside the fragment like this:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(...);
```

When you should be doing this instead:

```
getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(...);
```

Use this same line of code, in your second Fragment to access the same loader, and show the data to edit. Once you edited it and updated the database, you need to call `forceLoad()` (since you are not implementing an observer in your custom loader), to load the new data into the loader:

```
getActivity().getLoaderManager().getLoader(loaderId).forceLoad();
```

When you go back to the first fragment, the view hierarchy will be created  and `initLoader()` called (normally is implemented in `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()`), which will directly call `onLoadFinished()` because the loader already exists and was already updated by the second fragment.

Comment: This seems to work well (getting the loader from the activity). I don't seem to need the forceLoad tough